# Django filter __lte __gte strings

Tags: python, django

I would like to filter models given a user input. For example the user would like to go on a cruise that is 1-5 days long. In the template I have a selector with these values (1-5, 6-9, 10-16, 17+).
In the view I create these as kwargs.

```py
def create_kwargs(from_date, nights):
    kwargs = {}
    got_nights = nights != '-'
    got_date = False if not from_date else True

    if got_nights and (not got_date):
        nights_kwargs(kwargs, nights)
    if got_nights and got_date:
        nights_kwargs(kwargs, nights)
        kwargs['start_months__contains'] = from_date
    if (not got_nights) and got_date:
        kwargs['start_months__contains'] = from_date
    return kwargs


def nights_kwargs(kwargs, nights):
    if '-' in nights:
        c_min, c_max = nights.split('-')
        kwargs['cruise_duration__gte'] = c_min
        kwargs['cruise_duration__lte'] = c_max
    else:
        kwargs['cruise_duration__gte'] = '17'
```

Than I feed these kwargs to the filter method:

```py
for i, area in enumerate(filter_areas):
    cruises = GeneralCruise.objects.filter(areas__contains=area, **kwargs)
```

Previously I tried to check equality and it worked:

```py
kwargs['cruise_duration'] = '1'
```

My problem is that if I write __lte or __gte it returns all the models even if they are not matching the criteria.
I read other questions regarding this and I think this should be working.

This is the model:

```py
class GeneralCruise(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    ship_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    ship_img = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    cruise_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    arrival = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    departure = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    cruise_duration = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    start_dates = models.JSONField(default=list)
    start_months = models.JSONField(default=list)
    cabins = models.JSONField(default=list)
    days_desc = models.JSONField(default=list)
    port_codes = models.JSONField(default=list)
    areas = models.JSONField(default=list)
```

Comment: Can you shar the relevant model? Are you sure it is triggering the `nights_kwargs` function?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I added the model. I printed the kwargs before feeding it into the filter and its correct.

Comment: `cruise_duration` is a `CharField`, that means that it will not order by value, but *lexicographically*.

Comment: Yes, but if you try '5' < '6' it is going to be True.

Comment: yes, but `'10' < '5'` is also true.

Comment: Also general tip, your code is more complicated than necessary. For instance `got_date = False if not from_date else True` do you even need this variable? You could have just checked directly `if from_date:` also you didn't need 3 ifs, just 2 are enough: `if from_date:    kwargs['start_months__contains'] = from_date` and `if got_nights:    nights_kwargs(kwargs, nights)`

Comment: Anyway I will change it to an IntegerField, it might solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that your `cruise_duration` field is a `CharField` so `gte` and `lte` don't behave how you would expect (say, if it were a `IntegerField`). You're comparing strings rather than numerical values.

To illustrate the difference:

```py
>>> "9" > "10"
True
>>> 9 > 10
False
```

You'll want to change your `cruise_duration` column type to a field type that can be compared based on cardinal value (like an `IntegerField`).

Accordingly, the inputs from your kwargs will also need to be sanitized and converted to integers when provided as the `__lte`/`__gte` arguments for filtering the model on that field.

Answer (score 1):

`cruise_duration` is a `CharField`, that means that it will not order by value, but *lexicographically*. For example `'10' < '9'` lexicographically, since the first characters are `'1'` and `'9'`, and `'1'` is first in the alphabet.

The most elegant solution is to make it a numerical field, like an `IntegerField`:

```
class GeneralCruise(models.Model):
    # …,
    cruise_duration = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    # …
```

This will likely result in some trouble with migrations where probably the most effective way to get rid of it is to remove all the migrations, and thus start over with a fresh database.

If that is not an option, casting it to an `IntegerField` is probably the most effective way.

In that case the queryset looks like:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast, IntegerField

GeneralCruise.objects.annotate(
    cruise_duration_int=Cast('cruise_duration', output_field=IntegerField())
)
```

and then filter with `cruise_duration_int__lte=…` and `cruise_duration_int__gte=…`. But this is not an elegant solution.

It is also a bit odd that your model only has `CharField`s and `JSONField`s. Usually one uses `ForeignKey`s to other models to avoid *data duplication*, and get the database in a [*database normal form*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).